# Documents Migrated from 2010 have bad Document IDs

Tags: document-library, 2013, document-id, document-center

I have done an upgrade for a SharePoint 2010 site collection to 2013.  The site collection in question is a document center and there were a few thousand documents contained in it.  Another person recently pointed out the Document ID search was not working, so I investigated and found that the links for each document's ID were still referencing the original SharePoint 2010 server, not the new server.  I attempted to assign new document ID's to the documents using the library settings but that did not do anything.  I also deactivated and reactivated the Document ID service feature on the site collection, to no avail.  How can I get this to match the current location?

Comment: Out of interest: Are you using a custom document ID provider / have customized the document ID or is it still SharePoint Standard?

Comment: it's OOB document ID functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document IDs are assigned and updated based on a timer job.  If deactivating and then activities the job did not update the Document IDs with the new path and info, I would focus on reviewing the status and result of the Timer Jobs.  Please note that these jobs run daily by default, though they should also be triggered by the activation process.  If they have not run, then I would manually run them.

The two jobs you are looking for are:

- Document ID assignment Work item that assigns document ID to all
  items in the site collection. Daily
- Document ID enable/disable Work
  item that propagates content type changes across all sites when the
  Document ID feature is reconfigured. Daily

Comment: Manually running these timer jobs seemed to do the trick!  I spot checked some documents and they all had the newer IDs.